# Why do I get an error referring to the plugin.yml when I reload my bukkit server?

Tags: java, yaml, minecraft, bukkit

I'm following a java tutorial on how to make plugins, but each time I try to run the plugins on my server, I get this message.

```
    >reload
[09:04:18] [Server thread/INFO]: CONSOLE: Please note that this command is not supported and may cause issues when using some plugins.

[09:04:18] [Server thread/INFO]: CONSOLE: If you encounter any issues please use the /stop command to restart your server.

[09:04:18] [Server thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[09:04:19] [Server thread/INFO]: Loaded 7 recipes
[09:04:19] [Server thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[09:04:19] [Server thread/INFO]: Loaded 7 recipes
[09:04:19] [Server thread/ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins/Listeners.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidDescriptionException: Invalid plugin.yml
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getPluginDescription(JavaPluginLoader.java:158) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ab38754]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:144) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ab38754]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:375) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ab38754]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R1.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:832) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ab38754]
    at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:620) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ab38754]
    at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:27) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ab38754]
    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:148) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ab38754]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:726) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ab38754]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R1.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:712) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ab38754]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.DedicatedServer.handleCommandQueue(DedicatedServer.java:372) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ab38754]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:342) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ab38754]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:963) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ab38754]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.MinecraftServer.v(MinecraftServer.java:811) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ab38754]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:155) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ab38754]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar does not contain plugin.yml
    ... 15 more
[09:04:19] [Server thread/INFO]: Server permissions file permissions.yml is empty, ignoring it
[09:04:19] [Server thread/INFO]: CONSOLE: Reload complete.
```

Comment: You don't have a `plugin.yml`, your plugin **must** have one. Have a read of this [Spigot wiki page](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/plugin-yml/) on the plugin.yml.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `plugin.yml` in your `src` folder of your plugin

[image]

You have to put at least thesevalues in the `plugin.yml`

```
name: TestPlugin
version: 1.0.0
author: McPlayHD

main: net.mcplayhd.testplugin.TestPlugin
```

where `main` points to your `JavaPlugin` class (the main class)

Like [Lucan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11916773/lucan) answered you can read more about all the contents of `plugin.yml` in the [Spigot wiki page](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/plugin-yml/)